# Changing specific column values based on conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have following dataframe named 'Saty' in R

| One_Day | Arrived_Date | Departure_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | 2022-01-10 | NA |
| No | 2021-05-12 | 2021-06-01 |
| Yes | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-01 |
| Yes | 2022-03-01 | NA |

I want to modify the dataframe, if the One_Day column value is 'Yes', my 'Arrived_Date' and 'Departure_Date' should be same, like below dataframe.

| One_Day | Arrived_Date | Departure_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-10 |
| No | 2021-05-12 | 2021-06-01 |
| Yes | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-01 |
| Yes | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-01 |

How to achieve this by coding in R ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is an `ifelse` statement.

```
library(dplyr)

Saty %>% mutate(Departure_Date = ifelse(One_Day == "Yes", Arrived_Date, Departure_Date))

  One_Day Arrived_Date Departure_Date
1     Yes   2022-01-10     2022-01-10
2      No   2021-05-12     2021-06-01
3     Yes   2021-12-01     2021-12-01
4     Yes   2022-03-01     2022-03-01
```

Comment: Thank you!, I also tried mutate, but i messed up with arguments order I think.

Answer (score 2):

With the shown data this also works: `coalesce`

Nevertheless, I am quite sure for your original data you will need an `ifelse` statement as @benson23+1 provided, but this is may be also interesting for you:

```
libray(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Departure_Date = coalesce(Departure_Date, Arrived_Date))
```

```
  One_Day Arrived_Date Departure_Date
1     Yes   2022-01-10     2022-01-10
2      No   2021-05-12     2021-06-01
3     Yes   2021-12-01     2021-12-01
4     Yes   2022-03-01     2022-03-01
```